# CakePHP complex find condition character in name

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

I would like to perform a find on MySQL database to retrieve all entries of which ID is uneven, status id is either 4 or 6 and of which the full name contains an 'e' character. The query is correct, apart from the last part of the conditions..

I would go for the SQL method to retrieve a word which contains an 'e', but this results in an error, which does not correspond with the dataset. What's wrong with my query? Thanks..

There is an error in this part..

```
'Employee.full_name LIKE %e%'
```

Complex conditions..

```
$conditions = array(
    'EmployeeFunction.id %2' => 0,
    'Employee.employee_status_id' => array(4,6),
    'Employee.full_name LIKE %e%'
);

$this->set('allOrders', $this->Employee->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'EmployeeFunction', 
        'EmployeeCompetenceLevel' => array(
            'CompetenceLevel',
            'Competence' => array( 
                'CompetenceCategory'
            )
        )
    ),
    'conditions' => $conditions
)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to my question.. CakePHP always expects a key => value pair..

Correct find conditions are:

```
$conditions = array(
    'EmployeeFunction.id %2' => 0,
    'Employee.employee_status_id' => array(4,6),
    'Employee.full_name LIKE' => '%e%'
);
```